# Git commit at the beginning of a project

Tags: git, visual-studio

I started a new Visual Studio Solution and added new empty Projects.
I was wondering if I should commit the changes made in the solution file / project file ? Does it make sense or is this some kind of overcommitting ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting all collaborators to also use Visual Studio it can make sense to add the project files to the git repo. A problem with adding such files, though, is that they most likely contain absolute paths to files/directories that are different on every computer (e.g. the user's home directory).

A better solution is to add those files to `.gitignore` and instead add scripts for generating the project files, if needed.

Comment: ...or you could just make sure that your project files use relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those files should be included. Find a standard Visual Studio gitignore and start by committing that first.